# Different text color in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to have different rows in different colors in a textarea? Have you an example for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set partial text color in JTextArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837848/how-can-i-set-partial-text-color-in-jtextarea)

Comment: Here is an example about [How you can highlight in JTextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10309277/1057230), though If you are more interested in changing the Foreground Colour, here is an example, [How to Change Text Colour with JTextPane](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9652143/1057230)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not with a `JTextArea`. You can, however, use a [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) which allows for attributes to be applied to text. If you want examples, take a look at the [Text Component Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).